# Icomoon, open-iconic SVG icons not displaying in the blazor page

Tags: blazor-client-side, iconic, icomoon

I'm trying to use **Icomoon** in my blazor project. I've already downloaded the icons.

**HTML**

```
<button class="search__button">               
    <svg class="search__button__icon">
         <use xlink:href="img/icons/symbol-defs.svg#magnifying-glass.svg"></use>
    </svg>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.search__button {
   &__icon {
    color: #444444;
    width: 1.75rem;
    height: 1.75rem;
  }
}
```

**The location of the SVG files**

[image]

**The result I'm getting**

[image]

Am I missing something? I think to have followed what it's said in the documentation.

Thanks for helping

## EDIT

In this documentation is says that the svg icon can be used as an image like this:

```
<img class="nav__level-item__icon" src="img/icons/svg/home.svg" alt="home">
```

When used like this, it's displaying.

```
&__icon {
    width: 1.75rem;
    height: 1.75rem;
    fill: #fff; //and/or color: #fff
}
```

The only problem with using it as an image is that I can't style it. So, at the end, I'm still stuck.

## EDIT 2

I tried to implement what's suggested in this [blog post](https://pjmagee.github.io/blazor-and-svg-files/). Icons are being displayed, I can't still style them.

Comment: It seems that, as of now, Blazor doesn't support inline use of SVG.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#scalable-vector-graphics-svg-images

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft SVG use is a still limited, in [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#scalable-vector-graphics-svg-images) it states

```
If you place an <svg> tag directly into a component file (.razor), basic image 
rendering is supported but many advanced scenarios aren't yet supported. For 
example, <use> tags aren't currently respected
```

If you use a `string` variable for the `xlink:href` attribute the icon will render after pre-rendering but would disappear as soon as the Blazor library was loaded in the client, but looks like there is a workaround.

Instead of putting the `svg` and `use` tags in the `.razor` file you can return a MarkupString instead, something like

```
<i class="icon">
    @IconMarkupString
</i>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string IconSprite { get; set; }

    private MarkupString IconMarkupString
    {
        get => new MarkupString($"<svg class='icon-sprite'><use xlink:href='{IconSprite}'/></svg>");
    }
}
```

Then used like

```
<SVGIcon IconSprite="img/icons/symbol-defs.svg#magnifying-glass" />
```

One thing that I did notice was in order to get the styling to work on the SVG element itself I had to add a separate class to the `SVG` tag otherwise the styling would not be applied even when using `::deep`.